# Adjust the default orientation on an Android tablet

Tags: tablet, orientation

So here's the low down: my tablet has this rather annoying feature where its default orientation for profile is set so that the power button is on the bottom. Because of this, I have accidentally powered out of several games by shifting my hold and shutting it down.

Is there some app or setting to change what the default setting is for orientation? (And if I could also adjust landscape, that would be great.)

Comment: Which tablet model and Android version are you using? Usually there's a "Lock rotation" or "Auto-rotate" setting to prevent this.

Comment: I agree with *Andrew* and most of the devices have a tile in Quick-Settings as well. In some devices, the setting is in **Settings -> Display**, for others its **Settings -> Accessibility**.

Comment: @AndrewT. The rotate lock gets superceeded by the app when I open it so it still goes back to what not was before.